# Save Configuration settings dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, settings

I have built an application in C#.net without any database. In this i have added some configuration settings in app.config file.  And to change this settings i have added form to take configuration input from user, now i want to save newly added configuration settings in app.config file.

I have tried to update appsetting blocks by varies method it saves configuration but next time when i execute exe file it reload settings which i have defined at build time instead of new configuration.  i have tried resource and settings for the same but not able to save newly saved configuration.

So how do i save newly added confutation settings in my app.config physically so that it execute next time with newly saved configuration. Or any different way to save configuration without any database.

Comment: I think this is a repeat of this question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522912/update-app-config-file-programatically-with-configurationmanager-openexeconfigur

Comment: thanks, it works... Actually i make a mistake in saving.