# How to update app settings key value pair dynamically on app.config file in c# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, appsettings

How to update app settings key, value dynamically on  app.config file in c# winforms.
Key,value are listed below

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="logPath" value="C:\EventLogs" />
    <add key="isScreenCaptureMode" value="false" />
    <add key="isStartOnSysStartUp" value="false" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: What about like that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10900411/1306012

Comment: I'd prefer to use [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/how-to-create-application-settings). You can create it programmatically or using designer.

Comment: I have already tried different ways. But the change is reflecting in app.config file.

Comment: *But the change **is** reflecting in app.config file.* isn't it what you are looking for?

Comment: @RezaAghaei. No the value not updating in app.config file

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.
OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
configuration.AppSettings.Settings["logPath"].Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
configuration.Save();
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
using System.Configuration;

Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
                config.AppSettings.Settings["isScreenCaptureMode"].Value = "true";
                config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
                ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

Comment: @Sabari I did the same. But the updated value is not reflecting in app.config file.

Comment: @vijesh Note that if you are running/debugging the application from Visual Studio, this will not update the App.Config file. Go to the bin/Debug folder, launch the application from there. Then the values will be updated in the YourApplication.exe XML Configuration file. You can open that file with notepad to view the change.

Comment: @Sabari, I have tried it, but changes were not updating in the file

Comment: I have created this test application for you with the same code I posted above. It is performing the functionality you are asking about.https://quickfileshare.org/6r3/Debug.rar

Comment: Put anything in the textbox, press update. Close the app and then check the WindowsFormsApplication6.exe.config file in notepad. Your value will be there.

Comment: Changing the first line to  
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.
            OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
. Its is working. I will update the answer. Thanks for your support bro